# Unexpected token error when using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Attempting to setup / populate a basic mongo db using the shell, I get the following error message.
I have tried different databases but the error is the same. Can anyone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
"user":"bob",
"email":"bob@home.com"
}
Mon May 26 00:54:28.228 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Attempting to setup / populate a basic mongo db using the shell, I get the following error message.

I have tried different databases but the error is the same. Can anyone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If `{ "user":"bob", "email":"bob@home.com" }` is the only statement you are using in the shell, and you are not using any commands or selecting a database, then that's what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you mentioned is just the document itself. Check out the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) for how insert works. To insert, you should use:

```
db.collection.insert()
```

An example of an insert with the document in your example:

```
db.collection.insert({ "user":"bob", "email":"bob@home.com" })
```

Edit---

To clarify, you must replace "collection", in the above example with the name of the collection you're trying to insert into.

Also, ensure that you're using the correct database. When you connect to the shell, select your db with:

```
use testdb
```